# долго грузится сайт (104: Connection reset by peer)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, puma

Долго грузится сайт, иногда в итоге выдает `502 Bad Gateway`

Места много, swap используется на 40/1024

А вот nginx в логах выдает ошибку `failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream`

Пробовал перезагружать nginx, puma, убивал процессы.

Подскажите как решить проблему с nginx?

Comment: Тут, полагаю, проблему с upstream'ом решать надо, а не с nginx...

Comment: т.е. с backend сервером, вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: Я не могу знать что у Вас за nginx'ом стоИт :)

Comment: я просто к тому, что сайт лежит не из-за этой ошибки. скорее это следствие, которое вызвано ошибкой на бэкенде)